# Icon not rendering properly in Firefox when adding them by SASS

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, icons, material-design

I'm trying to override an icon in an angularjs component that I have no control over. It's a stepper library called [md-steppers](https://github.com/ipiz/md-steppers). I was able to change the current step icon in chrome. Here is how I did it.

```css
/* ... */
&.md-active md-step-label-wrapper {
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: flex;
    &:before {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        content: '\E150';
        color: white;
    }
}
/* ... */
```

As you can see I'm altering the icon by loading the font `Material Icons` and then changing the `content`.

This solution is working great in Chrome. I'm having a few problems in firefox, however. The icons does not seem to be rendering properly when I'm at 100% ( or less ) zoom. Everything above that seems fine.

[image]

You can compare the image above with the result on Chrome ( both at 100% zoom )

[image]

The result on Firefox seams a little bit *Blurrier* and not well formed.

I'm aware that this might be a bug in Firefox itself as [it has been reported before](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=995813). I saw a few workaround that revolve around the `mask` css property but I'm not sure it can apply to me, since i'm not using `mask` at all. This is assuming the icons are rendered as SVG.

I've already look up [CSS - Using SVG mask not displaying correctly in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298016/css-using-svg-mask-not-displaying-correctly-in-firefox) and [Firefox not rendering svg properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317591/firefox-not-rendering-svg-properly) on the topics but I could not make it work.

Am I missing something here and what can I do to correct this ?

[Here is a Jsfiddle with the problem occurring](https://jsfiddle.net/Nic2555/a7dfuzrL/12/).
The problem seams to be present in the iframe, in chrome as well.

Comment: Also, there seems to be no SVG involved whatsoever.

Comment: I have edited my question according to your comments. Thank you for pointing it out. @Rob

Comment: If you'd manage to extract effective styles into minimal working example we could help you better.  Looking at your code and GH sources https://github.com/ipiz/md-steppers/blob/master/dist/md-steppers.css#L395-L402 it's hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: @myf I've created a JSfiddle with the problem occurring. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Icons look pixel-perfect for me in the fiddle, using the latest Windows version of Firefox and latest Chrome Dev build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** I can't verify that any of the solutions I've written below work as I can't replicate the issue on my device in the JSFiddle you provided.
>   It displays fine for me in Firefox and Chrome. FWIW: I'm using a Mac
>   Mini on MacOS 10.14.6 with a 4K display @ 1920 x 1080 (i.e. HiDPI).
>   The same browser (i.e. Firefox) may handle fonts differently on
>   depending on operating system and hardware setup.

### Solution

The [demo link](https://ipiz.herokuapp.com/demo/index.html) for [md-steppers](https://github.com/ipiz/md-steppers) uses SVG data in the CSS:

```
.md-step.md-complete md-step-label-wrapper::before {
    content: '\7';
    background: #106cc8 url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.87)" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 16.17L4.83 12l-1.42 1.41L9 19 21 7l-1.41-1.41z"/></svg>') no-repeat center center; }
```

[See Line 398](https://ipiz.herokuapp.com/md-steppers.css)

I would probably try using this same method and avoid using the icon font if you think this is where the issue is arising from. If you also have the same issue in Firefox at the `md-steppers` demo link above then I guess the issue is bigger than just icon fonts and is also affecting SVGs. You can scroll down further to: **Other Possible Fixes**.

The Material Design icons can be downloaded in SVG format from [here](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=edit&style=baseline).
Use the search filter in the sidebar and type in `edit` for the icon you want, then press the `[Download] SVG 24` button in the bottom left corner.

The icon you download will be the default black colour so there are some changes you will need to make in order to make it suitable for you to use.

Open up the downloaded SVG in a code editor and refer to the way the SVG is formatted in the CSS for the `md-steppers` demo. Change the `height` and `width` properties, and also add the `fill` property to the `<svg>` tag, so it should look something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.87)"><path ...leave as is... /><path ...leave as is... /></svg>
```

Copy the SVG code as a single line and use it in a similar way that it's used in the `md-steppers` demo CSS:

```
.md-step.md-active md-step-label-wrapper::before, .md-step.md-success md-step-label-wrapper::before {
    content: '\7';
    background: #106cc8 url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.87)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>') no-repeat center center;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wx0brdjL/

**Alternatively,** you can save the SVG after you modify the width/height/fill to a file, then reference it in your CSS like:

```
background-image: url('edit-24px.svg');
```

---

### Other Possible Fixes:

If using the SVG above is still causing things to blur on Firefox, or if you want to stick with using the icon font, there are a few things to try which might fix the way that the icon font renders on your device:

---

**Option 1**

Applying `transform: translateZ(0)` to either `&.md-active md-step-label-wrapper` or `&:before`.

---

**Option 2**

Applying the [font-smoothing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) (see Firefox specific vendor prefix) or [text-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) CSS properties. Keeping in mind that changes here might affect the way it renders on someone else's device.

---

**Option 3**

I just came across [this open issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/648) on the Material Design Icons Github where a user recommends using this CSS hack: `transform: rotate(0.03deg)`

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue with the jsfiddle you supplied (all icons look okay for me). But I have had similar issues myself with other font-icons.

I think the issue comes from the `font-weight: bolder;` you've added to the parent element in your code. The browser now also wants to make the icon bolder, but since there isn't a "bolder"-version of the icon the browser tries to do it by itself and thereby making the icon look weird.

Your fiddle doesn't have the `font-weight: bolder;`, so im thinking your issue might have something to do with that. Try and remove it and see if the issue still persists.